# Understand the meaning of UPDATE_BEFORE of RowKind

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading the javadoc of `RowKind#UPDATE_BEFORE`, it says:

```
    /**
     * Update operation with the previous content of the updated row.
     *
     * <p>This kind SHOULD occur together with {@link #UPDATE_AFTER} for modelling an update that
     * needs to retract the previous row first. It is useful in cases of a non-idempotent update,
     * i.e., an update of a row that is not uniquely identifiable by a key.
     */
    UPDATE_BEFORE("-U", (byte) 1),
```

I would ask:

1. if the row `is not uniquely identifiable by a key`, how does flink know which row to retract, I think there must be a unique key to identify the row?
2. It says it is useful for `non-idempotent update`, what does `non-idempotent update` mean here?

Comment: Could some one help explain my questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. in table api, a row can have a primary key.
2. consider this situation

id  |  data

1   |  data_1

2   |  data_1

if we have a table like above. We can update a row like "update data set data='data_x' where id = 1" in this case, the id isn't update which is "idempotent update"

but if we have a table like this (lacking of id field)

data
data_1
data_1

then update to the second row is "non-idempotent update" since we don't have a id or something unique to identify that row object.

Comment: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/#examples-for-fromchangelogstream

this link maybe useful for you